# What is the method for mapping 200k records on Google Maps API via MYSQL db?

Tags: google-maps-api

I have a simple Google Maps api linked to MYSQL. I am trying to map a mysql table of 200k records. I have a default display of this data set as heatmap, so am not trying to map 200k markers. Even still, the app freezes, but I am unable to get a specific error.

Is there an another method I should apply? (i.e., data compression)

Comment: your have to filter by bounding box https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#putting-it-all-together (google maps api is not designed to map 200k records in one attempt) you might have better luck with fusion tables